# python regular expression to ignore a few characters

Tags: python, regex

In python3, I need to extract a 10-digit number from a sequence in the format of `555=AB:C$: EF 1234567890`, how should I do that? The string between `=` and 10-digit string can be pretty much any character,while the length of those characters is always 10... I tried to use `re.compile()`, but wasn't able to set the appropriate patterns yet. Any suggestion is welcome!

EDIT #1: the string has in total 20 characters, with the last 10 digits, and the first 10 can be anything (space, alphabet, $ or other symbols, and digits). Hence, I wasn't able to identify a good pattern yet.

EDIT #2: The problem is that I can't really identify which character it is at the end of the string (the string is a portion of a big file). The character after this string is something that doesn't seem to have uniform display in windows/linux/unix. Hence, I'm trying to locate it from the beginning, not from the end. Thanks!

Comment: Does `s[-10:]` work for you?

Comment: What patterns have you tried, and how did those patterns not behave as you expected?

Comment: If you want to extract a 10 digit number, `r'\d{10}` might be worth a try.

Comment: So, if I understand your 2nd edit correctly, you need to identify those 20 characters within a much bigger body of text first, so you can then extract the last 10 digits? In this case, show us a more comprehensive example (i.e. some of the sourrounding text and more examples for the stuff you want to match).

Answer (score 2):

If those 10 digits are *always* the last 10 characters in the string, you can just to `s[-10:]`, as suggested in the other answer.

If that is not guaranteed, just use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) searching for, well, 10 digits, and ignore the rest of the string. The pattern for this is `\d{10}`, i.e. `\d` for digit and `{10}` for ten times.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "555=AB:C$: EF 1234567890"
>>> re.search(r"\d{10}", s).group()
'1234567890'
```

---

According to your statement:

> The string between = and 10-digit string can be pretty much any character,while the length of those characters is always 10

If you need to find those numbers within a much larger body of text, you can search for a `=`, followed by 10 characters of anything, followed by 10 digits, i.e. `=.{10}\d{10}`

```
text = "foo bar not a block 1234567890 blub stuff 555=AB:C$: EF 1234567890 more unrelated stuff and another block 555=AB:C$: EF 1234567890 and finally more stuff"
p = re.compile(r"=.{10}(\d{10})")
for x in re.finditer(p, text):
    print x.group(1)
```

Output are the latter two groups of `1234567890`.

Answer (score 0):

If the 10 digit string is always at the end, you should be able to extract them with

```
>>> "555=AB:C$: EF 1234567890"[-10:]
'1234567890'
```

Edit:

According to your edit you don't need a regex. If your string is always 20 characters long you can just use normal string operations in python. So either `[-10:]` or even `[10:]`

```
>>> "AB:C$: EF 1234567890"[10:]
'1234567890'
```

Take the latter, if you want to handle your string from the beginning.

And if you can't use the string to the end, since you don't know where it ends you can just use

```
>>> "AB:C$: EF 1234567890"[10:20]
'1234567890'
```